# Subscribe based on other emissions

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an observable that emits values. Based on these values I need to subscribe/unsubscribe to/from another Observable.

Is there a handy way of doing so? A convenient way instead creating a field for the subscription and handling it manually?

Example:
`Observable A` emits `Boolean`s. If it emits `true` then a subscription should be made to `Observable B` - if `false` this subscription should be unsubscribed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if we're 100% on the same page but I think you're missing one point. Maybe you'll think I'm nitpicking, but I think it will be good to get our terms straight.

`Observable` starts emitting values when a `Subscriber` **subscribes** to it. So unless you're thinking about two separate `Subscribers` you can't react to an emitted value with a **subscription** because the `Observer` won't emit anything.

That said... what (I think) you wanna do could be done this way:

```
Observable<Boolean> observableA = /* observable A initialization */;
final Observable<SomeObject> observableB = /* observable B initialization */;

observableA
        .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<SomeObject>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<SomeObject> call(Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (!aBoolean) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("A dummy exception that is here just to cause the subscription to finish with error.");
                }
                return observableB;
            }
        })
       .subscribe(
                new Action1<SomeObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(SomeObject someObject) {
                        // THIS IS A PART OF THE SUBSCRIBER TO OBSERVABLE B.
                        // THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED ONLY IF THE OBSERVABLE A RETURNED TRUE
                    }
                },
                new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                        // A dummy Action1 so the subscription does not crash on the Exception
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Maybe the solution I was thinking about does not exist. Yes I was thinking about two subscriptions. Even though I prefer just having a field for the subscription and storing the subscription there / unsubscribing it instead of using the implicit onError unsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

If all of observables has the same type or  you can combine whatever you want based on values.

```
Observable.from(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5})
    .filter(i -> i < 5) // filter out something
    .flatMap(i -> {
        if (i < 2) { // subscribe on some observable, based on item value
           return Observable.just(i);
        } else {
           return Observable.just(3);
        }
    })
```